# $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial r^2}$ in terms of gradients (in rectilinear coordinates)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Is this equation correct?

$$ \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial r^2} = \nabla (\nabla f \cdot \hat r) \cdot \hat r $$

where $\hat r$ is the radial coordinate in the spherical coordinate system.

Comment: Is $r$ a vector?  If so, how are you taking a partial derivative with respect to $r$?  If not, how are you taking a dot product with $r$?

Comment: sorry, should be $\hat r$, the radial unit vector of the spherical coordinate system